# Запуск метода за два дня до установленной даты C#

Tags: c#, таймер

Как запускать какой либо метод в определенное время каждый день?
Например у меня есть сегодняшняя дата 06.05.2017. Студент оплатил за обучение до 10.05.2017. Мне нужно за два дня до 10, т.е 08.05.2017 вывести оповещение о том, что скоро нужно платить. Для этого каждый день мне нужно запускать метод сверяющий даты, т.е 6 запускаем, затем 7 числа и т.д.

Comment: Ну так настройте таймер на раз в сутки, и там сверяйте даты, в чем проблема то?

Comment: А как установить интервал таймера на каждый день именно в заданное время?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: проект на WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то типа этого. И вообще, привыкайте искать информацию самостоятельно, на MSDN есть описания всех необходимых классов - и таймеров там 5 штук на любой вкус и написано как с ними обращаться.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval= 86400000;  ///24*60*60*1000 в мс, как водится

        timer.Tick +=TimerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var TimeNow = DateTime.Now;

        if (TimeNow.Day == SomeDay-2)
        {
            \* Делаете что надо*\
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) я подумал о том что можно задать интервал в таком виде, но почему то мне показалось, что это будет выглядеть не совсем красиво что ли) а так такая идея была)

Comment: Не, вот как-то так, вполне норм. Ну, если ответ вас удовлетворил - примите его.